# Viewing a Twitter tag in multi-column format

Tags: windows, twitter

I'm looking for a program for Microsoft Windows or web-based that can view a Twitter tag in a multi-column format.

E.g. https://mobile.twitter.com/ThailandVoice/status/1251148658034135044/photo/1:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One can use [TweetDeck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TweetDeck):

- https://tweetdeck.twitter.com/
- gratis for now. However, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TweetDeck:

  > Beginning in August 2023, Tweetdeck will be only available to verified accounts.

  and one has to pay to be a verified account.
- has several viewing options:

[image]